# REACT: Is there a better way to set state for multiple items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is how I wrote all my items in state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
            displayInfo: 0,
            name: '',
            phone: '',
            mail: '',
            title: '',
            city: '',
            description: '',
            linkedin: '',
            github: '',
        }
}
```

Is there a better way I can write them in state without having to write them individually like this?
For example I did update their values in state using:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        })
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is fine. You can also do:

```
handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
  this.setState({
    [name]: value,
  })
}
```